# Permission denied while using runtime in android application

Tags: android, runtime, superuser

When trying to execute shell commands on Lollipop I am getting permission denied error.

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su")

I do have super user permission in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER"/>
```

The device is rooted.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Since your device is rooted, you can try installing the apk in the system directory:

`system/app`

Certain 'serious' permissions are granted only to apks in this directory. (On your rooted device, browse to this directory in your file browser, and you will find all pre-installed apks here).